# separate functions from gui into process. lagging

Tags: python, interface, pyqt, pyqt5

first i created the functional parts of my code and later decided to add a interface to it, so i have linked the interface and and the main function of the previous code as bellow.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(921, 988)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.sheet2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.sheet2.setObjectName("sheet2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.sheet2)
        self.sheet1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.sheet1.setObjectName("sheet1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.sheet1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 921, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        # self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        # self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def update_sheet2(self, Image):
        qim = ImageQt(Image)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        pix = pix.scaled(self.sheet2.width(), self.sheet2.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.sheet2.setPixmap(pix)
        self.sheet2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def update_sheet1(self, Image):
        qim = ImageQt(Image)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        pix = pix.scaled(self.sheet1.width(), self.sheet1.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.sheet1.setPixmap(pix)
        self.sheet1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


def run_ui():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.background = main(w)
    t = Process(target=w.background.process)
    t.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the function named `main(ui)` in this code, the codes where it uses the ui is as follows. and i used the `run_ui()` function to run the code

```
def main(ui):
    for i in range(100000000):
        x=1
        y = x*x*x
    img = Image.open('XXX.png'.format(GRAY_PATH,1))
    ui.update_sheet1(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_ui()
```

and i have passed the ui 'w' as an argument to the main funciton, where it uses that reference to call the update_sheet1,2 functions with image data.

this lags the GUI and its always not responding and the images also do not  appear on the GUI.

i think this has something to do with the way i liked the interface. but dont know how to fix it.

thanks for any help.

Comment: provide a [mcve]. Qt does not support multiprocessing so you should not modify the GUI from another process. And that is probably the cause of lag.

Comment: @eyllanesc, okay i will write a shorter main function, with the relevant part in it. i will change soon so u can see if that is ok.

Comment: Changing `Process(target = w.background.process)` to `Process(target = w.background)` and `img = Image.open('XXX.png'.format(GRAY_PATH, 1))` to `img = Image.open('XXX.png') `for obvious reasons and does not generate any type of lag. So your code is not an MCVE

Comment: still lags, the code is still doing the exact same thing

Comment: How to point out your code is not an MCVE since it does not reproduce your problem

Comment: now it will, i added a range for the lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt does not support multiprocessing so to remove complexity from the problem use threading. In this case Qt also indicates that the GUI should not be modified from another thread, instead of that I create a QObject and export it to the other thread, this QObject has a signal that transports the image.

On the other hand when you do main(w) you are invoking the heavy task in the main process and that causes the GUI to freeze, instead you have to pass the name of the function, and the arguments of that function through of args:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from threading import Thread

# ...

class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    imageSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(Image.Image)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def update_sheet2(self, Image):
        # ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(Image.Image)
    def update_sheet1(self, Image):
        qim = ImageQt(Image)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        pix = pix.scaled(self.sheet1.width(), self.sheet1.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.sheet1.setPixmap(pix)
        self.sheet1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


def run_ui():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    signaller = Signaller()
    signaller.imageSignal.connect(w.update_sheet1)
    t = Thread(target=main, args=(signaller,), daemon=True)
    t.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


def main(signaller):
    for i in range(100000000):
        x=1
        y = x*x*x
    img = Image.open('XXX.png')
    signaller.imageSignal.emit(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_ui()
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i want to ask, was that for loop truly  necessary to give this answer.

Comment: @Eshaka Yes, because with your sentences in your publication you could think very different things, and this also reinforces that you were using "animation" in an inadequate way, besides you do not seem to differentiate between threading and process as the title of your question showed. In conclusion, many times it has happened to me that the OP for ignorance or any other reason does not know how to use the correct words,

Comment: @Eshaka [cont.] causing it to be interpreted in many ways and I trying to implement what it says does not reproduce its problem or reproduce it but the problem that I get is different to what the OP gets so my solution is not suitable for the OP, and just the OP provides a code that is an MCVE, .... Do you realize how much time and effort has been lost? If the OP had provided the MCVE we would have saved so much time. So the responsibility of the OP is to provide the best possible MCVE.